# Structuring cucumber feature files for various mobile devices

Tags: selenium, appium, cucumber-jvm

I'm building Mobile apps test automation using Java, Cucumber-JVM, Appium.

For various scenarios, in order to make scenario verbose, we have added following line at the start of scenario/scenario outline / background of bdd feature files.
for example:

```
 Given user with ios device "iPhone SE Simulator"
 And I select a book product
 And I select layout type "Square"
```

..
Another example

```
 Given user with ios device "iPhone 7"
  And I select a book product
  And I select layout type "Square"
```

..
Another example

```
 Given user with ios device "iPhone 6"
  And I select a book product
  And I select layout type "Tav"
```

Now, we have got many devices, so what will be the best way to reuse the step.
I would like to avoid using Scenario Outline & parameterize on  type?

Also, we're okay for slight repetition/duplication of feature files, if it helps to easily build test suite.

Kindly suggest

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using the device parameter from story line, you consider passing it with before hook or test parameter. So that same scenario can be repeated for multiple devices.

Comment: pass the devcie from command line like  -Ddevice="iPhone 7", and get the device argument value in beforeAll() hook,

Comment: We would like to keep the story self-explanatory i.e. 1st line of the story should declare which mobile device its going to execute against. Also lot of underlying code has been built around this way of passing Mobile-type as a parameter in the BDD. Kindly suggest in this case./ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) you can simply define and use property

property file:

```
device.name=<your device name>
```

BDD

```
Given user with ios device "${device.name}"
```

Further more qaf supports [different way to set properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html) as well as [strong resource management for different environments](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to achieve this without QAF : Given user with ios device "${device.name}"?

Answer (score 0):

1) specify the device from command line:

```
-Ddevice="iPhone 6"
```

2) capture the device from command line in before All hook

```
class CLIParams {
  private static String device;
  public static void setDevice();
  public static String getDevice();
}

class Hook {
  @BeforeAll
  public beforeAll() {
    CLIParams.setDevice(System.getProperty("device", "iPhone 7"));
  }
}
```

3) step in feature file

```
Given user with mobile device "iPhone SE Simulator"
Given user with mobile device "iPhone 6"
Given user with mobile device "Google Neux"
```

4) step definition of the first line

```
Given("^user with mobile device \"(.?)\"$", (device)->{
  // ignore the deivce from the step description
  // instead to use the device from command line
  CLIParams.getDevice();
})
```

5) how to pass jvm args in eclipse
[image: eclipse run configuration]

For other IDE, Intellij/NetBean should also has similar place to specify jvm args, if you run by command line just append -Ddevice="iPhon 7" to command

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. Could you please advise how to pass -Ddevice="iPhone 6" in non maven environment set-up. i.e. running Cucumber runner in local environment.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating further. I have added above-referred step-defs in my feature file. But only last one is getting executed: Given user with mobile device "Google Neux". I am not clear how parameter gets passed from  do you meant we need to make the device as a parameter , something like - <device> (similar to what we do in example table). Kindly elaborate. Thanks

Comment: please split the three Given into 3 scenarios in one feature file, maybe only one Given statement allowed for per scenario .